# The name 'id' does not exist in the current context in Javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, lambda, url-parameters

I cannot use the parameter passed to my javascript method in lambda expression by trying several ways as shown below. How can I use id parameter in the expression below? Thanks in advance.

There is a hyperlink in the FileName and I pass the ID parameter to the Javascript method successfully:

```
<a onclick="downloadFile(@p.ID);">@p.FileName</a>

function downloadFile(id) {
    $.fancybox({
        //This works: (p.ID == 82)
        content: '<img     src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == 82 ).FileData)" alt=""/>',

        //They are not works: (p.ID == id / p.ID == @id  / p.ID == this.id)
        content: '<img src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id ).FileData)" alt=""/>',

        content: '<img src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == @id ).FileData)" alt=""/>',

        content: '<img src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == this.id ).FileData)" alt=""/>',

        type: "html"
    });
}
```

**Update:** Here is the Ajax method that I used before

```
function downloadFile(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Issue/RenderImage",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': id }),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (response) {
            $.fancybox({
                content: '<img height="200" width="250" src="data:image/png;base64,' + response.Image + '" />',
                type: "html"
            //});
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("an error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am guessing here but i assume that your value `id` is not set. Is your error message client side (in the browser dev console) or server side? What is the context - how do you call `downloadFile()` and when and how is your c# code `... FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == @id ) ...` generated? 
More details and code (server side, generated html, the html page) would certainly make it easier to help.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree I updated my question. Please be sure that the id parameter is successfully pass to the Javascript method (I checked in Firebug). Any idea?

Comment: Do you know js can not call method from behind directly,if you want call,you need ajax,the first method can be called success,because the id you input is 82, it is  a int number,and it can be understand by NET

Comment: @SkyFang Actually first I used Ajax, but I heard that "there is no need to use AJAX for such a kind of operations. Images are separate resources for a page and are loaded as separate requests already. Just link to it:" as indicated on [this](http://www.widecodes.com/7NzmqqjXgk/display-image-using-ajax.html) page. On the other hand, there is no problem except from passing id in my javascript method. So, what do you think? Do I have to use Ajax for this? If so, could you post an AJax method that is suitable for image and excel/pdf files that can be opened by clicking the link I post above? Thank

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Why vote down instead of helping?

Comment: Ok, the problem was solved with the help of @SkyFang's helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the final working status of the code by modifying the @Sky Fang's answer so that someone need to use it. I also pass the title parameter to the javascript method.

**View:**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json

<a onclick="showImage(@p.ID, '@p.FileName - @p.Created - @p.AuthorID');">@p.FileName</a>


<script>    
function showImage(id, imageTitle) {
    $.fancybox.showLoading(); //Shows loading animation 
    var allImages=  @(new HtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FileAttachments.ToDictionary(k=>k.ID,v=>System.Convert.ToBase64String(v.FileData)))));
    $.fancybox({
        'scrolling'         : 'no',
        'titleShow'         : true,
        'title'             : imageTitle,
        'showCloseButton'   : true,
        'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
        //'titleFormat'     : formatTitle,
        //'transitionIn'    : 'fade',
        //'transitionOut'   : 'fade',
        //'speedIn'         : 600,
        //'speedOut'        : 200,
        'overlayShow'       : false,
        content: '<img style="height:500px; width:auto;" src="data:image/png;base64,'+ allImages[id] +'" />',
        type: "html"
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody told you there is no need ajax, it seems the image data can be post to page,just like dictionary,you can change your code ,and put your `Model.FileAttachments` to be part of js,just like

```
var allPictures= @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FileAttachments.ToDictionary(k=>k.ID,v=>System.Convert.ToBase64String(v.FileData)));
function downloadFile(id) {
    $.fancybox({
        content: '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+allPictures[id] +'" alt=""/>',
        type: "html"
    });
}
```

And you said you want to download other file types (pdf, etc),it can not be like image,you can use code like these if there is no limited to download the file

```
<a href="filePath">fileName</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'. On the other hand, if you suggest me tos use Ajax instead of this, could you please post the Ajax sample by updating my Ajax method above? I want to list all the image, png, and other file types (pdf, etc) as hyperlinks and when clicking this link I want to openimage files and download other file types. Any help pls?

Comment: Voted+, but need to solve the problem for selecting as answer.

Comment: I lost `SerializeObject` before,and other file can not be download by fancybox,fancybox is just a Jquery plugs for light box effect,and I aready answered how to download the othe file types

Comment: If you want user click the image to download the file,you just need to add `a` to container 'image',like `<a href="filePath"><image /></a>`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. With the help of your, I solved the problem and posted the final code so that someone can also used it. Voted+